# qtree and tikz-qtree

Tags: linguistics, tikz-qtree, qtree

I need to use `tikz-qtree` instead of `qtree`, but I noticed that trees are annoyingly uneven. Compare the following tree created with `tikz-qtree`:

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree, pst-node, pst-asr, graphicx}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
%\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}

\Tree [  [  [ $\sqrt{\textsc{Root}}$ {\scshape Voice} ] [.{\scshape Asp} ] ] [.{\scshape Tns} ] ]

\end{document}
```

[image]

with the following created with `qtree`:

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree, pst-node, pst-asr, graphicx}
%\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}

\Tree [.  [.  [.  $\sqrt{\textsc{Root}}$ {\scshape Voice} ] [.{\scshape Asp} ] ] [.{\scshape Tns} ] ]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to compiles trees with `tikz-qtree` as nice as those with `qtree` somehow?

Comment: You can use `forest`'s `linguistics` library with `nice empty nodes` and `sn edges` in most cases.

Comment: Why do you need `tikz-qtree` rather than `qtree` exactly?

Comment: I need it to draw arrows between nodes...

Comment: You could use `tikzmark` with `qtree`. I've added a solution based on this to my answer below. I would probably use this if I didn't want to change to `forest` and think about using `forest` for future projects, if applicable. That is, unless somebody like Alan Munn comes along with a `tikz-qtree` solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT (Now with 3 solutions)

### `qtree` + `tikzmark`

If you just need to draw arrows later, you can use `tikzmark` with `qtree`. At least, the following seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\begin{document}
  \Tree [  [  [ {\tikzmark{a}$\sqrt{\textsc{Root}}$\tikzmark{b}} {\scshape Voice} ] [.{\scshape Asp} ] ] [.{\scshape {\tikzmark{c}Tns\tikzmark{d}}} ] ]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw [->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] ($(pic cs:a)!1/2!(pic cs:b)$) .. controls +(1,-2) and +(-1,-2) .. ($(pic cs:c)!1/2!(pic cs:d)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>qtree</code> + <code>tikzmark</code>]

### `forest`

I would also use Forest, but would definitely recommend the `linguistics` library which provides `nice empty nodes` and suitable edges out-of-the-box. To align the terminal nodes, you can add a phantom with zero width but appropriate height.

For example,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  nice empty nodes,
  for tree={
    font=\scshape,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    where n children=0{
      +content=\makebox[0pt]{\phantom{$\sqrt{X}$}},
    }{}
  }
  [
    [
      [
        [$\sqrt{\textsc{Root}}$]
        [Voice]
      ]
      [Asp]
    ]
    [Tns]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest with <code>linguistics</code> library]

### `tikz-qtree`

If you prefer to stick with `tikz-qtree`, you should wait to see what Alan Munn can come up with. I've only ever used `qtree` and `forest`, so the best I can do with `tikz-qtree` is

[image: <code>tikz-qtree</code> effort]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\newlength\widesttreenodewidth
\settowidth{\widesttreenodewidth}{$\sqrt{\textsc{Root}}$}
\newlength\highesttreenodeht
\settoheight{\highesttreenodeht}{$\sqrt{\textsc{Root}}$}
\newlength\deepesttreenodedpth
\settodepth{\deepesttreenodedpth}{$\sqrt{\textsc{Root}}$}
\tikzset{
  every tree node/.append style={text width=\widesttreenodewidth, text depth=\deepesttreenodedpth, text height=\highesttreenodeht, text centered},
  execute at begin node=\makebox[0pt]{\phantom{$\sqrt{X}$}},
}
\Tree [  [  [ $\sqrt{\textsc{Root}}$ {\scshape Voice} ] [.{\scshape Asp} ] ] [.{\scshape Tns} ] ]
\end{document}
```

### Note

Forest does take some time to learn and the syntax is a bit different, so it is not something to attempt at the end of a large project, deadline looming, for sure.

Answer (score 6):

Not `qtree` nor `tikz-qtree` but `forest` :):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={% style of tree
  font=\scshape,
  anchor=base,
  calign=fixed edge angles,
  delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate}{}},
  inner sep=1pt,
}
[
  [
    [
     [$\sqrt{\textsc{Root}}$] [Voice]
    ]
    [Asp]
  ]
  [Tns]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't learn another package right now, so I was wondering if there is a way to do it with `tikz-qtree`

Comment: For example, to  me learning `forest` make me less troubles than learning `tikz-qtree`. Let me emphasize that it was developed  for use in linguistic. And here on site are many active many excellent gurues, who will be glad to help you. Don't hesitate to start use it,First example you already have, and on the site are plenty more complicated examples.

Comment: Yes. But the syntax is different and it has a rather steeper learning curve than `tikz-qtree`. If @RobertP. has a project with trees in `tikz-qtree`/`qtree` syntax it is non-trivial to convert them all and attempting to learn Forest should not be attempted with a clock ticking against an imminent deadline, for example. At least, I surely wouldn't like to do it and would not recommend it.